# Как реализовать аналог Promise.all() c очередью?

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, очередь

Как реализовать `Promise.all()` с динамической очередью фиксированной ёмкости,
то есть чтобы в отдельный момент времени в обработке находились, например, до 10 параллельных запросов?

```js
const promises = [...Array(10)].map((item, i) => new Promise((resolve) => resolve(i)))

const arr = await PromiseAllByChanck.all(promises , 2)
```

Другими словами, чтобы запросы выполнялись сегментами массива запросов, поблочно?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48345606/executing-100k-promises-in-javascript-in-small-50-chunks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело в том, что каждый созданный [Promise](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise) по сути и является запросом, отправленным на исполнение, поэтому в искомом решении не может быть такой сущности как массив "обещаний" `promises`.

То есть они все создаются и "отправляются на исполнение" прямо с этой строки:

```js
const promises = [...Array(10)].map((item, i) => new Promise((resolve) => resolve(i)))
const five = await promises[5] // 5
```

Чтобы предотвратить это, можно "экранировать" их, точнее преобразовать в асинхронные функции:

```js
const tasks = [...Array(10)].map((item, i) => async () => i)
const five = await tasks[5]() // 5
```

Тогда аналог `Promise.all()` со внутренней очередью будет выглядеть примерно так:

```js
// interface Task<R> {
//   (): Promise<R>
// }

// const delay = <R = void>(ms: number, value?: R) =>
//   new Promise<R>((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(value), ms))
const delay = (ms, value) =>
  new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(value), ms))

// parallelLimit = async <R>(tasks: Task<R>[], limit: number): Promise<R[]> => {
const parallelLimit = async (tasks, limit) => {
  if (limit < 1) throw new Error('[TaskManager] Размер очереди меньше единицы.')

  const taskStack = [...tasks]
  const results = Array(tasks.length) // : R[]
  const executors = Array(limit)
    .fill(null)
    .map(() => async () => {
      let task // : Task<R>
      while ((task = taskStack.pop())) {
        const index = taskStack.length
        results[index] = await task()
      }
    })
  await Promise.all(executors.map((run) => run()))

  return results
}


;(async () => {
  const samples = [...Array(10)].map((_, i) => i)
  const tasks = samples.map((s) => () => delay(samples.length - s, s))
  const results = await parallelLimit(tasks, 2)
  console.log(JSON.stringify(results))
})()
```